# Lego Boost Variable setting

Tags: boost

I'm trying to program steering for a Logo Boost Model. Motor B spins a certain angle and the steering works. To get it running the model - the app - needs to know the current position of the wheels in order to spin the motor correctly. I created several macros where i decide on, and set, a variable. I initialize the model by setting the variable in the main screen of the program interface. But if I go into my steering macros this variable is not known. Instead I can set the variable within. It means, I cannot have a global variable which can be read and set from within macros?

Can anybody clarify or elaborate this?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this site:
https://legoboost.blogger.de/stories/2709388/

It is in German but I think this picture:
[image: https://cdn.blogger.de/static/antville/legoboost/images/einstellungprogrammierbloecke.png]

is the important one.

After these settings you have a global value in the white program block.